# FileMaker 13 GetThumbnail Anomaly?

Tags: containers, thumbnails, filemaker

I have a container field named tempImage, set to have a calculated value of:

```
 GetThumbnail(tempImage; 500; 500)
```

However, when I drag a larger size image into that field, the image does not get resized.

How can I fix this?

Note: The "Do not replace existing value of field (if any)" checkbox is unchecked.  [Here is a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ayyyxvdmagh1y9m/FileMaker_GetThumbnail_Anomaly.mp4) to a video showing the anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific answer, but will offer a method to debug this.

Instead of dropping the image into the container, write a script that is triggered by the OnObjectModify that sets another container field using the GetThumbnail() function.

In so doing, you will be able to run the debugger and see if an error is generated by the script.  That will give you more information to post here if you have not solved this already.

Reference information:
http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/func_ref1.31.14.html

Here is a detailed blog post about this function:
http://hbase.net/2013/07/11/resizing-images-in-filemaker-pro-12/`